# Interpreting standard error for similar (but different) specified linear regression models: R

Tags: r, regression

I get different standard error values depending on the way I specify a linear regression model (for categorical variable) in R.

For example,

```
library(alr4)
library(tidyverse)

FactorModel <- lm(I(log(acrePrice)) ~ I(as.factor(year)), data = MinnLand)
summary(FactorModel)
```

[image: Specifying a standard regression model]

However, if I specify a regression model with "+0", the standard error (and consequently other values) are different.

```
FactorModel1 <- lm(I(log(acrePrice)) ~ I(as.factor(year)) + 0, data = MinnLand)
summary(FactorModel1)
```

[image: Adding +0 gives me a different result]

How do I know which one is the correct standard error? I kinda understand how to interpret the estimates. For instance, in the first model if I want to know the estimate of 2003, its intercept + the coefficient of 2003. However, in the second model, it automatically calculates the actual value.

Is there a similar interpretation for standard error?

Comment: Please read the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag regarding posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first model has an intercept but the second model has no intercept at all so they have different residuals.  They therefore have different residual standard errors given that the standard error is an estimate of the standard deviation of the residuals. Since they are different models they also have different coefficient and coefficient standard errors too.  We can see that the intercept in the first model is significant (it has three stars beside it) but you can also compare the models using `anova`:

```
anova(FactorModel1, FactorModel)
```

Use `predict` to get predictions but it will be easier to use it if you first put the transformed variables in the data frame and then use those instead of trying to transform them in the formula.